# append "www" before every url in a html document using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I need to append www before every url [if there is not already] in any anchor tag or any form action [i.e. any link lies in the DOM] using jquery. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Can you post your attempts at solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wont cater for `http://` (and other variants) but you could do this...

```
$("a").each(function(){
   var href = $(this).attr("href");
   if(href.indexOf("www.") != 0){
      $(this).attr("href", "www." + href);
   }
});
```

the `form` tag uses the `action` attribute, so if you want that too you will have to do some additional code. Either check the tag name, or create a new loop just for forms. Something like this:

```
$("a, form").each(function () {
    var attr = $(this).prop("tagName") == "FORM" ? "action" : "href";
    var href = $(this).attr(attr);
    if (href.indexOf("www.") != 0) {
        $(this).attr(attr, "www." + href);
    }
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nx7vs/)

NOTE: This is just an example. There are a number of things to consider. I have already mentioned the scheme issue (http etc.), then you have to consider relative paths (i.e. "/folder/page.html"). It all gets a bit messy, are you sure this is actually what you need to do?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No There is no relative path. Also there is no https .. only http ... after doing ... some modification in your code it's work perfectly. So.. thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('href').indexOf('www')!=0){
            $(this).attr('href', 'www.'+$(this).attr('href'));
        }
   });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sUddn/1)